# Every night count an number

Tags: php

For an project in Visual Basic, I need a site (script) that every night reset the number on the site to 1.

So if it is 00:00 then it will reset the number on the page to 1, and repeat that every day.

I tried this code :

```
<?php
//Kijken of het 00:00 is
if(date('H') == '00'){
//Het is 00:00 uur dus ik geef 1 weer
  $tijd = 1;
} else {
//Het is nog geen 00:00 uur dus ik geef 0.
  $tijd = 0; 
}
if($_GET["tijd"]){
    $tijd = $_GET["tijd"];
}

//het bestand schrijven
$file = 'nulofeen.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
$current = $tijd;
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);

//Open het bestand
$file = file("nulofeen.txt");
//Lees de laaste regel uit
for ($i = count($file)-1; $i < count($file); $i++) {
//echo de laaste regel
  echo $file[$i];
}
?>
```

But that won't work it wont't reset anything.

Comment: Use cron task. Impossible in php

Comment: // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    // Append a new person to the file
    $current = $tijd;

What's the use of it? Why do you even read it? First line is bogus.

Comment: Your file/code above wont run by itself. To make your PHP script carry out those tasks you require, you need to run on the PHP server, usually through a web browser. Otherwise, it's just a file, with code in it, sat on a hard drive waiting for you to do something with it.

Comment: Just save a file with "lastreset" as the current date.
Check if the "lastreset" is lower than the current date, update the lastreset in the file and RESET what you want to reset ...
In this way, you will get a reset with the first access of the script in a given day ... regardless if it's 0:00 or 12:00 or so ...

Answer (score 3):

You need to setup a `Cron job`. This will run your script every night, and from there you can store the number `1` in your file. Also, no need to run the time check, just have the cron run at midnight.

Cron syntax, in case you're unaware:

```
00 00 * * * php path/to/your/script.php
```

That will run a file every morning at midnight. This assumes you're using PHP, and that you are running on linux.

The OP brought up another point in his comments, this may help future readers. Other people than yourself *will* be viewing your site, so you need a way to automatically load in the current number value on page load. To do this, either setup a database and update the number to be shown at midnight, or read from the text file (see OP) on each page load.

Comment: and how do i let it count a number on a page ? sorry im totally nub at php/html visual basic oke but this no :$

Comment: and how do i do that ? haha sorry for my qeustions im a complete nub about this :(

Comment: @superpro500 Mark this question complete and open another question, honestly that's what you should do. Or, take some time off from questions and read a bit. There is a lot to learn.

Comment: i have read alot but i just dont understeand it ?0.o
tried multiple things but it gives me an error (cant open file ) or it is just keeping on 0, or i cant find the file 0.o

Comment: hmm yeah i need to but i never tried things like this and read allot but i will make an new qeustion mark..
i will close it thanks

Answer (score 0):

create a cronjob that will run every night at midnight:

`00 0 * * 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 php /path/to/your/script.php`

this script will rewrite to the file "1" every time its run

```
<?php

$file_name = "test.txt";
$fh = fopen($file_path, "w") or die("cant open file");
$toFile = "1";
fwrite($fh, $toFile);
fclose($fh);
```

?>

Comment: it keep saying "cant open file" how do if it ? i am using your script, but what things in your script do i need to change to make it work?

Comment: maybe change the permission of the file:                                                `chmod 755 /path/to/your/test.txt` and `chown your-user /path/to/your/test.txt`